# How define own guards in/for SanitizerCoverage to prodive coverage for libfuzzer

Tags: code-coverage, fuzzing, libfuzzer

i am using Clion 2020.3.1, and clang/llvm version 10.0.0

i want to direct libfuzzer to a specific code coverage. So i can define my own edges or decide which code is necessary to obtain.
Right now libfuzzer just counts the edges (?) or codes lines he obtains during the fuzzing.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The header mentions sanitizer, but there is nothing about it in the question. Do you want' to direct fuzzing to some code snippet ignoring others?

Comment: as libfuzzer counts the edges/lines of code it reaches, but i want to manually tell the libfuzzer which lines count as a coverage.

Comment: Libfuzzer supports instrumentation on source file level. When the code you don't want to instrument is in separate files, you can build these files without instrumentation.